# Ensure unique id by checking value in DB which returns mono

Tags: spring-boot, spring-webflux, project-reactor, reactive

There is a requirement to generate a unique id based on a format received from request.
Before inserting to DB, need to check if it already present, then generate a new if not present in DB.
Currently, using Springboot 3, reactive.

Need some guidance on following code.

Expectations:

- Create a unique id based on format.
- Check if record already present in DB
- Generate a new id if already present
- Try generating a new id 10 times, otherwise error

How to check record exists in DB and keep generating until filter condition match?

```java
// DB CRUD operation service for Group table
// Group record is unique by groupId and type
@Autowired
final GroupService groupService;

public String newUniqueId(String format, String groupId) {

    // try 10 times to generate a unique id
    return IntStream.range(0, 10)
        .mapToObj(i -> newIdByFormat(format))
        .filter(newIdByFormat -> isIdUnique(newIdByFormat, groupId)) // Need some guidence here
        .findFirst()
        .orElseThrow(() -> new RuntimeException("Could not generate unique id"));
}

private String newIdByFormat(String format) {
    // Map<String, Supplier<String>> map;
    return map.get(format).get();
}

private Predicate<String> isIdUnique(String groupId) {
    // This call returns, Mono<Group> group = groupService.query(id, groupId)

    return id -> groupService.query(id, groupId)
    .filter(Objects::isNull); // How to return boolen value here?
    
   // tried calling .block() here, but fails with exception
   // block()/blockFirst()/blockLast() are blocking, which is not supported in thread reactor-http-nio-4
}
```

```java
public Mono<Group> createGroup(Request) {

    return transformRequest(request)
}

private Mono<Group> transformRequest(request) {
  String uniqueId = newUniqueId(request.format, request.groupId);
  
  return dbService.save(new Group(uniqueId));
}
```

Thank you for your time.

Comment: In general it's `retry` or `retryWhen`, but your code doesn't look like a reactive code so it's hard to suggest where to use it in your case.

Comment: @IgorArtamonov Unfortunately, there are no line numbers, but `groupService.query(id, groupId)` this call returns a `Mono<Group>`

Comment: Added more code (the caller side) to the question

Comment: I guess you can add `retry` right after. But again, everything else is non-reactive so I don't see much sense in having just this small part as a reactive code, as you don't really get anything from it

Comment: Thank you @IgorArtamonov. There is one thing I would like to learn more "everything else is non-reactive". My understanding, call to `transformRequest()` is Mono  (the argument request is the result of `ServerRequest.bodyToMono().flatMap())`-> call to `groupService.query()` is Mono. Maybe I am missing something ?

Comment: Ah, I see, you actually have the reactive parts. It's just confusing that you also have Java streams and blocking code as well. I guess I may suggest how to rewrite the code, but I'm not sure I can give you a fully working solution, but can show an idea

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
private Mono<Group> transformRequest(request) {
   // newUniqueId() must return a Mono. 
   // otherwise you start to execute the code right in this method, which is not reactive. 
   // Ex., a non-mono executed even if the result is cancelled. 
   // Reactive code executed only when it actually needed. Like lazily
   Mono<String> uniqueId = newUniqueId(request.format, request.groupId);

   return uniqueId.map { id ->
       new Group(id)
   }.flatMap { group ->
      // .save() should be a Mono
      dbService.save(group).thenReturn(group)
   }
}

public Mono<String> newUniqueId(String format, String groupId) {
    Mono.fromCallable {
        // Callable executed only when it's actually subscribed
        newIdByFormat(format)
    }.flatMap { id ->
        groupService.query(id, groupId).retry(10)
    }         
}
```

Comment: Amazing!! I am yet to try this, but looks promising. Thank you. Appreciate it! Curious to know, the `.retry(10)` will be executed once per `newIdByFormat(format)`, right ?

Comment: Yes, one call for `newIdByFormat`, and the retry only `groupService.query`

Comment: Thank you @IgorArtamonov. Much appreciate it! I have tried this approach. Using retry (which triggers on error) it executes mono. I have tweaked it for the use case. `Mono.fromCallable(() -> newIdByFormat(format)).flatMap(id -> groupService.query(id, groupId).flatMap(found -> Mono.error(new RuntimeException("already present"))).switchIfEmpty(Mono.just(id)))).retry(10)`

Comment: I see. As I understand, `query` returns an existing item for an `id` which wasn't clear for me, and in this case your version looks right. I'm glad it helped